# try .. catch not working in Application_Start

Tags: asp.net

I have some code in Application_Start enclosed in a try .. catch block (Application_Error doesn't work at this point, so you need to use a try .. catch block). For some unknown reason the application acts if the try .. catch block is not there. I get the usual ASP.NET error page ("Server Error in '/' Application.") with the exception details for Exception ("Test Exception") not for FatalException.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Text Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FatalException("Application startup error", ex);
    }
}
```

It's an ASP.NET 2.0 application

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What's a FatalException? Can you supply the class for repro?

Comment: @urig, actually this is a custom exception class that derives from Exception. It only calls the base class constructor in its constructor, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached the debugger to the Application_Start event yet?  are you sure the app is not already running in the background? Mind, the App_start will always be fired only once, not for every instance of global.asax floating around.

For more info, look [here](http://odetocode.com/Articles/89.aspx)

Comment: Actually I'm not debugging. I'm just requesting a page through the browser

Comment: then probably the app is already running, the very first time it will call app start, but when you request it it has already done that, and as i said, app start will be the very thing called and only once

Comment: The application is not running in the background, I get the exception details in Application_Start for "Test Exception" as I noted in he question. I touch the web.config file to force a restart.

Comment: What happens if you don't rethrow the exception?  Could asp.net be giving you the innerexception somehow?